# How to add class on condition in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs (Nextjs),I have "Home page" and few other pages (about,services...etc),For integrate in Nextjs, I created "_document.js",Problem is there is no class attached with" tag" in home page but class added on "about, service and rest of page", so how can i add "class" according to page? In other words i want to add class "main-layout inner_page" on all pages except "home page",How can i do this ? Here is my "_document.js" file

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript,link } from 'next/document'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
        <Head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

Comment: follow component pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would specify the layout that I use per page:
[NextJS Layout per-page](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts)

But you can also pass props to your Layout from _app or from your page, example:
(Not so recommended approaches)

```
const CustomApp: FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps, router }) => {
  return (
      <MainLayout
        hasContainer={pageProps.hasContainer}
        hasSecondClass={['/', '/company'].includes(router.pathname)}
      >
            <Component {...pageProps} />
      </MainLayout>
  );
};
```

And your page can change the hasContainer

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => {
  return {
    props: {  hasContainer: false },
  };
};
```